# returning a bit type in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bit

I have a stored procedure in which I am validating some columns to return a value of 1 or 0.

The stored proc code block is:

```
, CASE WHEN 
    (PolicyStartMileage < LossMileage) 
    AND (PolicyStartDate <= LossDate) 
    AND (Certified = 0) 
     THEN '1' 
     ELSE '0' 
     END
     AS Certifiable
```

My question is, how do I return '1' or '0' as a bit type?

In my codebehind, I am using:

```
Boolean.Parse(item.GetDataKeyValue("Certifiable").ToString());
```

in order to read the value (true or false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the data to be a true BIT data type you need to do a cast, otherwise it will default to numeric.

```
CASE WHEN 
    (PolicyStartMileage < LossMileage) 
    AND (PolicyStartDate <= LossDate) 
    AND (Certified = 0) 
     THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) 
     ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
     END
     AS Certifiable
```

If you do the cast, you can call the GetBoolean() method from the data reader directly avoiding the parse

Answer (score 1):

```
, CASE WHEN 
    (PolicyStartMileage < LossMileage) 
    AND (PolicyStartDate <= LossDate) 
    AND (Certified = 0) 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
     END
     AS Certifiable
```

> **when you use Quotes around 1 or 0 it treats it as a string not
>   integer.**

Comment: your suggested code was returning an error in my codebehind "string was not recognized as a Boolean"

Comment: @Csharp just seen the edit in your question, it would have worked if you were only using it in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the quotes `''` around `1 and 0` so that it behaves as `integers` rather than `string`. like this:

```
, CASE WHEN 
(PolicyStartMileage < LossMileage) 
AND (PolicyStartDate <= LossDate) 
AND (Certified = 0) 
 THEN 1 
 ELSE 0 
 END
 AS Certifiable
```